# Counting in other bases

Tags: combinatorics

While this could be considered opinionated to a certain degree, by setting the requirement as ease of use, is there a base that is better for performing simple math functions (+-×÷) than base ten.

I recently attended a lecture about whether cover stories affect the learning of students. One of the controls was not having foreign exchange students. Questions regarding this control started, and eventually it was implied that foreign number systems (Chinese) might be better than ours. I attributed this to them using a different base.

Comment: This question is too broad. Perform simple math functions for what purpose?

Comment: Sometimes I do math for fun, so I am wonderinf whether learning a different base would be beneficial in any way.

Comment: Base $1$ is pretty easy. Though the only number you can represent is $0$.

Comment: @Meelo Not necessarily so: [Unary numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)

Answer (score 2):

Some points to consider in choosing a base:

(1) In lower bases there are very few $1$-digit facts to learn, but the numbers are longer.

(2) In higher bases, the numbers are shorter, but there are a lot more facts to learn.

(3) Certain bases give quick divisibility tests for certain numbers.  For instance in base $12$, there are instant divisibility tests for $2, 3, 4, 6, 12$, just by checking the last digit.